# How to generate bash command from array and command template?

Tags: bash, code-generation

Now I use this bash command:

```
$ yarn b types && yarn w types && yarn g types && yarn s types
```

Is it possible to generate command like this in bash? (pseudo code):

```
$ exec ['b', 'w', 'g', 's'].map(input => `yarn ${input} types`).join(" && ")
```

If it is possible, which syntax will be here?

I am going to use this script in my package.json file (node). yarn workspaces foreach not suitable here, because of its poor output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Good-Practice Alternative: Use A Loop

Code generation has serious security implications and is generally only for experts. Moreover, in present circumstances, you don't need it: a loop will suffice.

```
buildAll() {
  for input; do
    yarn "$input" type || return
  done
}
buildAll b w g s
```

...has identical behavior, exiting early with a nonzero status if any of `yarn b type`, `yarn w type`, `yarn g type` or `yarn s type` fails, and exiting with a successful/zero status if all four succeed.

As a one-liner, this would be:

```
buildAll() { for i; do yarn "$i" type || return; done; }; buildAll b w g s
```

---

This doesn't change in any substantial way if your items are in an array; if you have:

```
types=( b w g s )
```

...then, just replace `buildAll b w g s` with `buildAll "${types[@]}"`

---

#### What You Asked For: Performing Code Generation

Before doing anything you saw here in your own code, review [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) regarding the security issues associated with `eval`.

The `${var@Q}` expansion requires bash 5.0 or newer; for older versions of bash, `printf %q` is the alternate way to escape variables' contents to be safe to parse as code. Note that this isn't any shorter or more readable than the alternatives above, and still involves a loop!

`:` is used as a synonym to `true`; it lets us make all iterations of our loop identical, unconditionally prepending a `&&`.

```
types=( b w g s )
statement=':'

for type in "${types[@]}"; do
  statement+=" && yarn ${type@Q} types"
done
eval "$statement"
```

The version with support for older versions of bash is:

```
types=( b w g s )
statement=':'

for type in "${types[@]}"; do
  printf -v type_q '%q' "$type"
  statement+=" && yarn $type_q types"
done
eval "$statement"
```

Comment: For completeness, the function isn't strictly necessary. An ad-hoc loop like `for i in b w g s; do yarn "$i" type || return; done` is fine as well.

Comment: @chepner, the problem is `|| return` -- not always valid if not in a function context. You could `|| break`, granted, if the exit status is going to be read immediately after the loop exits; but using a function is just generally more explicit. But yes, if you look in the revision history, unless I overwrote it inside the grace period, the first draft of this answer was `for i in b w g s; do yarn "$i" type || break; done`. (Edit: Looks like I _did_ overwrite that inside the grace period, so it's no longer in evidence).

Comment: Gah, yeah, typo on my part. Also, I forgot that `break` sets the value of `$?` to 0, so you would lose the exit status of the offending `yarn` command.

Comment: @KamilCuk, if you're going to reintroduce your answer, consider making it `xargs -I{} sh -c 'yarn "$1" types || exit 255' _ {}`, keeping the substitution out of the section parsed as code and safely treated only as data